# RGB LED strip controlled through PySerial only somewhat functional

Tags: arduino-uno, rgb-led, python, led-strip

I am trying to set up an LED-strip of 30 RGB LEDs (model WS2801). The strip is connected to an Arduino Uno and an external power supply and the goal is to send colors to the arduino using PySerial which are then shown on the LED strip.

I have been trying to wrap my head around the communications, which I am having a hard time with, especially due to the loose typing of python.

I wrote some code that generates smooth color transitions and got the strip to actually show a fairly smooth color transition, unfortunately the colors are the wrong ones.

Now I am guessing something overflows somewhere, especially since colors such as 0xFF0000 (red) show as a yellow tone, which indicates that on top of red some green gets added as well.

The Python code using pySerial:

```
@classmethod
def set_lights(self: RGBHardware, colors: List[int]) -> None:
    for i in range(len(colors)):
        rgb = color_to_rgb(colors[i])
        self.arduino.write(chr(76).encode()) # 'L'
        self.arduino.write(chr(i).encode())
        self.arduino.write(chr(rgb[0]).encode())
        self.arduino.write(chr(rgb[1]).encode())
        self.arduino.write(chr(rgb[2]).encode())
    self.arduino.write(chr(90).encode()) # 'Z'

@classmethod
def turn_on(self) -> None:
    self.arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)
    if self.arduino.isOpen:
        self.arduino.close()
    self.arduino.open()
    pass
```

The code running on the Arduino Uno:

```
void setup() {
#if defined(__AVR_ATtiny85__) && (F_CPU == 16000000L)
  clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1); // Enable 16 MHz on Trinket
#endif

  Serial.begin(115200);
  strip.begin();
  // Update LED contents, to start they are all 'off'
  strip.show();
}

void loop() {
   while (Serial.available()) {
        uint8_t serial = Serial.read();
        if (serial == 'Z') {
            strip.show();
        } else if (serial == 'L') {
            int i = getNextInput();
            int r = getNextInput();
            int g = getNextInput();
            int b = getNextInput();
            strip.setPixelColor(i, Color(r,g,b));
        }
   }
}

uint8_t getNextInput() {
  while(!Serial.available()); // wait for a character
  return Serial.read();
}
```

I am having the strong feeling I am just missing a miniscule detail and it is quite frustrating.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
So I recorded some data and pasted the results below. I found that always not the whole LED-strip was updated and none of it with the correct color. Once even the character "Z" seemed to go missing (that causes the strip to fully refresh) so no color was showing at all.

What I also forgot to mention earlier was that I am using Celery in Python to do the light switching as a background task.

To record the results I used

`print("i, R,G,B: " + str(i) + ", " + str(rgb[0]) + "," + str(rgb[1]) + "," + str(rgb[2]))` to print the data in python and

`Serial.println("i, R,G,B: " + String(i) + ", " + String(r) + "," + String(g) + "," + String(b));` to do the same on the Arduino.

Sending color red from Python:

```
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,121: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 0, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,122: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 1, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,123: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 2, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,125: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 3, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,126: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 4, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,127: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 5, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,127: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 6, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,128: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 7, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,129: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 8, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,129: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 9, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,131: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 10, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,132: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 11, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,132: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 12, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,133: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 13, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,134: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 14, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,136: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 15, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,137: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 16, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,139: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 17, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,140: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 18, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,141: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 19, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,142: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 20, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,144: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 21, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,145: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 22, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,146: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 23, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,147: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 24, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,148: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 25, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,149: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 26, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,150: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 27, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,151: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 28, 255,0,0
[2018-07-23 16:13:57,151: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] i, R,G,B: 29, 255,0,0
```

Received color red on the arduino:

```
i, R,G,B: 0, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 1, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 2, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 3, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 4, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 5, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 6, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 7, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 8, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 9, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 10, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 11, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 12, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 13, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 14, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 15, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 16, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 17, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 18, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 19, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 20, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 21, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 22, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 23, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 24, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 25, 195,191,0
i, R,G,B: 26, 76,27,195
```

Sending color green from Python:

```
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,374: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 0, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,376: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 1, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,377: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 2, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,378: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 3, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,380: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 4, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,381: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 5, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,382: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 6, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,383: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 7, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,384: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 8, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,385: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 9, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,386: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 10, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,387: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 11, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,387: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 12, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,388: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 13, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,389: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 14, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,389: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 15, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,390: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 16, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,390: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 17, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,391: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 18, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,392: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 19, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,393: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 20, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,393: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 21, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,394: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 22, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,395: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 23, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,395: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 24, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,396: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 25, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,397: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 26, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,398: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 27, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,398: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 28, 0,255,0
[2018-07-23 16:22:34,399: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] i, R,G,B: 29, 0,255,0
```

Received color green on the Arduino:

```
i, R,G,B: 0, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 1, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 2, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 3, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 4, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 5, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 6, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 7, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 8, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 9, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 10, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 11, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 12, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 13, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 14, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 15, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 16, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 17, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 18, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 19, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 20, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 21, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 22, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 23, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 24, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 25, 0,195,191
i, R,G,B: 26, 76,28,0
```

Sending color blue from Python:

```
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,416: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 0, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,416: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 1, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,417: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 2, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,417: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 3, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,418: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 4, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,418: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 5, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,419: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 6, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,419: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 7, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,420: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 8, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,420: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 9, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,421: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 10, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,421: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 11, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,422: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 12, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,422: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 13, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,423: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 14, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,423: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 15, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,424: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 16, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,424: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 17, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,425: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 18, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,426: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 19, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,427: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 20, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,427: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 21, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,428: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 22, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,428: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 23, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,429: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 24, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,429: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 25, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,430: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 26, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,430: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 27, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,431: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 28, 0,0,255
[2018-07-23 16:26:52,431: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] i, R,G,B: 29, 0,0,255
```

Received color blue on the Arduino:

```
i, R,G,B: 0, 0,0,195
i, R,G,B: 1, 0,0,195
i, R,G,B: 2, 0,0,195
i, R,G,B: 3, 0,0,195
i, R,G,B: 4, 0,0,195
i, R,G,B: 5, 0,0,195
i, R,G,B: 6, 0,0,195
i, R,G,B: 7, 0,0,195
i, R,G,B: 8, 0,0,195
i, R,G,B: 9, 0,0,195
i, R,G,B: 10, 0,0,195
i, R,G,B: 11, 0,0,195
i, R,G,B: 12, 0,0,195
i, R,G,B: 13, 0,0,195
i, R,G,B: 14, 0,0,195
i, R,G,B: 15, 0,0,195
i, R,G,B: 16, 0,0,195
i, R,G,B: 17, 0,0,195
i, R,G,B: 18, 0,0,195
i, R,G,B: 20, 0,0,195
i, R,G,B: 23, 191,76,26
```

Sending color orange from Python:

```
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,725: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 0, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,726: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 1, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,727: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 2, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,728: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 3, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,729: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 4, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,731: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 5, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,732: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 6, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,733: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 7, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,734: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 8, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,735: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 9, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,736: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 10, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,737: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 11, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,738: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 12, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,739: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 13, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,740: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 14, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,741: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 15, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,742: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 16, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,743: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 17, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,744: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 18, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,744: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 19, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,745: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 20, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,746: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 21, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,747: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 22, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,747: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 23, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,749: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 24, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,750: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 25, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,750: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 26, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,751: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 27, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,752: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 28, 255,128,0
[2018-07-23 16:29:20,752: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] i, R,G,B: 29, 255,128,0
```

Received color orange on the Arduino:

```
i, R,G,B: 0, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 1, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 2, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 3, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 4, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 5, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 6, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 7, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 8, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 9, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 10, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 11, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 12, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 13, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 14, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 15, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 16, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 17, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 18, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 19, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 76, 23,195,191
i, R,G,B: 194, 128,0,76
```

Received color orange on the Arduino (again):

```
i, R,G,B: 0, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 1, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 2, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 3, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 4, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 5, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 6, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 7, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 8, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 9, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 10, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 11, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 12, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 13, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 14, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 15, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 16, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 17, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 18, 195,191,194
i, R,G,B: 128, 0,76,24
i, R,G,B: 27, 195,191,194
```

Another Edit:
What is also interesting is that the main color (e.g. when I send red most of the LEDs are yellow) stays the same every time I tried. 
But the amount of LEDs that gets passed differs with each try. The same goes for the last one or two LEDs the Arduino receives. Their colors and indexes are all over the place.

Comment: `generates smooth color transitions` .... do not send transitions ..... send discrete colors to the whole string  0xFF0000, 0x00FF00, 0x0000FF, 0xFFFF00 ... etc ...............document the resulting color ...... check color value on the web ....  http://html-color-codes.com/       ................ update your question with results

Comment: Red and green produce yellow. I think you are seeing cyan 0x00FFFF. It kind of looks like the bits are inverted.

Comment: @jsotola I added some sample data, maybe you could take a look again?

Comment: @Gerben That was a mistake on my end, red actually show up as yellow on the strip.

Comment: Try using a lower baudrate and see if the problem persists.

Comment: You don't seem to be using the [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview) correctly

Comment: @Gerben Thank you, after reducing the baud rate to 57600 all lights look the same (still the same wrong color though). Unfortunately the weird behavior persists if I leave the color printing on, so apparently the Arduino Uno is a little too weak for doing both.

Comment: @esoterik Can you elaborate?

Comment: @smoelge chr(rgb[0]).encode() is a little bit obtuse; you are making an arbitrary chcaracer of an int, then encoding it, when you should just call .to_bytes on it. ex. rgb[0].to_bytes(1,'big') or simple convert all 3 at once with bytes(rgb)

Comment: @smoelge, you have to start at bottom and work your way up .... remove all code that has anything to do with the LEDs  .... send only single bytes and receive only single bytes, with a pause in between ..... if that has no errors, then send two bytes and test again .... reinsert the LED code only after the serial comm is reliable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
...
  self.arduino.write(chr(76).encode()) # 'L'
  self.arduino.write(chr(i).encode())
  self.arduino.write(chr(rgb[0]).encode())
  self.arduino.write(chr(rgb[1]).encode())
  self.arduino.write(chr(rgb[2]).encode())
self.arduino.write(chr(90).encode()) # 'Z'
...
```

should be spelled:

```
  self.arduino.write(b'L')
  self.arduino.write(i.to_bytes(1,'big'))
  self.arduino.write(bytes(rgb))
self.arduino.write(b'Z')
```

It is much more readable this way; you could refactor even further:

```
  sout = b'L' + i.to_bytes(1,'big') + bytes(rgb)
  self.arduino.write(sout)
self.arduino.write(b'Z')
```

Your also wasting effort here:

```
Serial.println("i, R,G,B: " + String(i) + ", " + String(r) + "," + String(g) + "," + String(b));
```

This should be said more like this:

```
Serial.print(i);
Serial.print(", ");
Serial.print(r);
Serial.print(", ");
Serial.print(g);
Serial.print(", ");
Serial.println(b);
```

This eliminates three temporary String objects you were creating with String().

The rest of the code looks like it should work so you should try trouble shooting, you could:

- Lower the baud rate till it works
- Try 9600 baud and increase it until it stops working
- Try the a serial sample program, make sure the serial portion is working correctly first
- Write your own minimal test program, make sure the serial is working correctly at first.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly.
And you are completely right about the String concatenation, I wasn't really paying attention to performance, due to those values just being printed for debugging.